# How to add all routes(of ReactJs application) to Nodejs application on Cpanel?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cpanel

I have set up Nodejs application(developed on ReactJs) in Cpanel. Everything works fine except I cannot directly browse to any route of the application. In Application Url I have the following setting `Application URL : subdomain.domain.com` . When I browse to `subdomain.domain.com` than everthing works fine. Even when I click some link to route to `subdomain.domain.com\routeA`, it works as expected.

But when I type `subdomain.domain.com\routeA` directly on the browser than I get `status code 500` error. using `Application URL : subdomain.domain.com/*` doesn't work either. How can I achieve this.

Comment: https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6

Comment: @imjared Thanks. I was missing the htaccess configuration. Now it works fine. If You answer the question I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: I am not sure why the down vote. Its a legit question and I have got legit answer for it too.

Comment: the downvote was probably because the answer was a simple google search. But idk, stackoverflow usually is tough to understand sometimes.

Comment: I did google for about an hour but most of the search lead to cpanel forum or stackoverflow with very less relevant questions. May be the keyword weren't correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a .htaccess file similar to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

source: https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6